# SQL "group by" like - grouping algorithm

Tags: sql, algorithm, group-by, jtable, grouping

I have a table with more than 2 columns (let's say A, B and C). One column holds some numbers (C) and I want to do a "group by" like grouping, summing the numbers in C, but I don't know the algorithm for doing so.

I tried sorting the table by each column (from last to first, aside from the numbers column (C), so in this case: sort(B) and then sort(A)) and then, wherever `n`th row holds same values in A and B as in `n-1`th row, I add the number from `n`th row to `n-1`th row (in the C column), and then delete the `n`th row. Else, if A or B value in row `n` differs from A or B value in `n-1`th row, I'll just move to the next row. Then I repeat the algorithm till the last row in table. But somehow this isn't working all the time, especially when there're a lot more columns (some rows remain ungrouped, maybe because of the sorting method).

I want to know whether this is a good grouping algorithm and I need to look for the problem into the sorting method, or I need to use another (sorting and/or grouping) algorithm and which one. Thank you.

LE: Apparently the algorithm that I used works well after a thorough check of the code and fixing some minor mistakes that junior programmers like me often make :)

Comment: Can you post some working code? It will help to understand exactly what you have done and propose an answer.

Comment: So for each group of rows with the same value in A and B, you want to sum the values of C? Don't really understand why you posted this under sql, when the question is related to a JTable.. Are you going to store the summed values, or just showing them in the JTable?

Comment: I just need to know the grouping algorithm used by "group by" statement in SQL in order to use it somewhere else (in a JTable for example). So it's just an algorithm issue, not an SQL or Java coding/syntax issue. That's why I didn't post any code.

Comment: The relational database-world is way different than the object-oriented world, even if you did find the algorithm used by sql, i doubt that it would be transferable to an object-oriented paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

I think a good way to do this would be to wrap your row into a class, implement the equals method, and then use a Map to add the values up:

```
public class MyRow {
    private Long columnA;
    private String columnB;
    private int columnC;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object other) {
        if (!other instanceof MyRow) {
            return false;
        }
        final MyRow otherRow = (MyRow) other;
        return this.columnA.equals(otherRow.getColumnA()) && this.columnB.equals(otherRow.getColumnB);
    }
}
```

Then you can iterate over all the rows, and create a Map for holding the sums of C.

```
final Map<MyRow, Integer> computedCSums = new HashMap<MyRow, Integer>();

for (final MyRow myRow : myRows) {
    if (computedCSums.get(myRow) == null) {
        computedCSums.put(myRow, myRow.getColumnC());
    } else {
        computedCSums.put(myRow, computedSums.get(myRow) + myRow.getColumnC());
    }
}
```

Then, to get the sum of grouped Cs of any row, you just do:

```
computedCSum.get(mySelectedRow);
```

Comment: Interesting approach... I never used HashMaps before, but this is a very good example to start working with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is three things should be considered about group by

1. less or equal is abstract
   comparing two rows A, B according it  columns (C1..Cn) are like this :  compare each column from C1 to Cn , if we can get which is less, then return ,or if the two values are equal, then we go to compare next, repeat this until return.
2. which algorithm we choose
   1)build a binary search tree or a hash table to store tuples , when we get a tuple, search the equal tuple , if we have , then merge the tuple which have the same group value, else put it to our search structure
   2) read some tuples, then sort , walk the buffer and merge the same group
   I prefer 1 rather than 2.
3. memory size
   if out input  is huge, we must consider memory limit.
   we can use merge algorithm to deal this.
   if memory exceed our limit , then write the tuples in memory to the tape order by their group columns
   when we finish reading the input, then merge the result set in tape.